# To generate the gamma function by integration....is a MacLaurin series legitimate?

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I've been trying to make sense of the gamma function and why some values pop up, like $\operatorname{\Gamma}\left (\dfrac{3}{2} \right) =\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

I'm still trying.

But here's a thought: what if you used the MacLaurin series for $e^{-x}$ instead. Here's what I came up with:

$n! = \displaystyle \int_0^\infty x^n \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k \cdot x^k}{k!} = \displaystyle \int_0^\infty \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k \cdot x^{k+n}}{k!}$

$=\left [\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k \cdot x^{k+n+1}}{(k+n+1) \cdot k!} \right]_0^\infty$

$= \left [\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k \cdot x^{k+n+1}}{(k+1)! + nk!} \right]_0^\infty$

Evaluating that at $0$ is just $0$, but it's the upper bound I'm worried about.

Is this reasoning:

1. Open to improvement or
2. Totally wrong?

Comment: Totally wrong. $x$ is a dummy in the expressions with an integral. However it's still here in the subsequent expressions, where you seem to have written the indefinite integral instead. And if you try to fix this and integrate $x^{n+k}$ on $[0,\infty)$, what do you get?

Comment: You mean in the second line? I thought that would be the full expression for $x^ne^{-x}$. And I'm still fresh in terms of integration techniques so I was trying to bring this thing to a level I could understand

Comment: Basically, you are writing that $\int_0^1 x\,\mathrm dx=\frac{x^2}2$, instead of $\int_0^1 x\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}2$. Is it clearer now? In your case the upper bound is infinite, and the problem is worse, because $\int_0^{+\infty} x^n\,\mathrm dx=+\infty$, which is not $x^{n+1}/(n+1)$. Note that here you have a good example of the fact the permuting limit symbols (like sum and integration) does not always work.

Comment: I get your argument. Let me set up the bounds properly this time. But I still wonder if I can get to $n!$ from that mess.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment: it's worse because you then get a series where all terms are infinite.

Comment: I'll stick to the integration by parts then. Thanks